is there a quicker way to save csv files as polars dataframes than using list comprehension?
I have 2 folders each containing 1507 csv files, i am using the following code to save each file as a polars dataframe using list comprehension:
bdsim=[pl.read_csv(x, schema_overrides = {"X0.6": pl.Float64}) for x in simpaths]
bdens=[pl.read_csv(x, schema_overrides = {"ridge_reg": pl.Float64}) for x in enspaths]

simpaths and enspaths are lists of the paths of each of my csv files and i am saving each polars dataframe in a list called bdsim and bdens. All files are on my google drive and i am using google colab. Currently it takes over 30 mins to run these two lines. How can i make it more efficient?
i´ve tried doing for loops but it´s not a very pythonic way to do it

Do you need to use read_csv? You can use scan_csv which returns a LazyFrame instead.

No, probably not.
The list comprehension is not what takes up the time here. Making a list-comprehension with 3000 objects is very fast, completely unnoticable in a 30min job (and the size of the objects does not matter for the speed of the comprehension, since the list-operations operate on references to your dataframes, they don't shuffle around all your data)
What takes up all the time is the actual reading of the csv-files into polars-dataframes, which can only be because there is lots of data. You can try to switch from csv to something less easy-to-use but more memory-friendly. I suggest you look into (in increasing level of difficulty to implement)

zipping them (creating .csv.gz for each of them)
Using hdf5 (A library/file-format for saving collections of multidimensional arrays to disk, a bit obscure though)
Building some kind of cache-logic so you only reload the csv that changed since you last put it in cache (you can use pickle and gzip to store dataframes in disk)

I have used all of these methods in the past for data-analysis. Specifically for data-analysis with jupyter and if your data rarely changes I would add the following though, which is by far the easiest:

load your data in the first jupyter-cell in the morning, then eat breakfast during the 30min, compute/explore/visualize on it for the rest of the day :)


also worth considering parquet with snappy compression

If the schema of the files is the same, it is faster to pass the argument to a single pl.read_csv() instance, so Polars can amortize the work over all arguments. This will help better parallelism.

Worth a try. But questionable if parallelism helps here; on a single-machine disk-bound-problem (which I suspect we have here), it usually doesn't, no matter how many cores you have.

pl.scan_csv can take a list of paths instead of a single path, and in general there's no reason not to use a LazyFrame
